# WMF rendered badly with PlayEnhMetafile

Tags: winapi, wmf

this is a question for somebody who is familiar with WMF/EMF formats.

I wonder why the attached metafile does not render correctly with PlayEnhMetafile (after conversion with SetWinMetaFileBits, I am testing it in Delphi). It does not render correctly with many other apps (e.g. Total Commander viewer, Irfanview,...) but renders correctly with MS Office 2010 image viewer.

Note: This image comes from RTF file produced by MS Word 2010 and is the result of Equation Object.

What could be the cause and how to render this image correctly.

[Link to image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100237088/test.wmf)

Comment: Can you show your code, an MCVE

Comment: I think first it would be nice to know why it renders differently in those apps I mentioned.

Comment: How would we know that without knowing how you render it? You won't show your code and you won't show how your image is rendered. It feels like you aren't fully committed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, He does say it renders correctly in Word, but not in other applications - which is readily reproducible.

Comment: @Mitch exactly! I played with WMFs long time ago but too few experience to answer myself now...

Comment: @user3777363, it looks like there is a spurious `R0005: [009] EMR_SETWINDOWEXTEX (s=16) {szlExtent(1366,768)}` which causes most clients to ignore the second window size, which is `R0011: [009] EMR_SETWINDOWEXTEX (s=16) {szlExtent(7104,992)}`.  That causes everything to smush on the X axis, but since it is EMF, all of the text is still drawn with the correct aspect ratio.  As for how to fix or compensate, I have no idea.

Comment: Ok. If this is not about the code, and is about the file, then so be it.

Comment: Presumably Word has its own WMF interpreter which is more tolerant than the one built into `PlayEnhMetafile`.

Comment: @Mitch thank you this must be the problem. Did you use some metafile dump tool for the file? If so please send me the link if it runs either on Win or Linux.

Comment: Found it myself: http://frazmitic.free.fr/emfexplorer/index.htm

Comment: @user3777363, yep.  That is the one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that the **Windows** metafile does not like getting converted to an **Enhanced** metafile.  The following code seems to render the `wmf` as intended:

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetMetaFile(string filename);

[DllImport("gdi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool PlayMetaFile(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr hmf);

var bmpNew = new Bitmap(7104, 992);
using (var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmpNew))
{
    var bmpHdc = gfx.GetHdc();
    var mfHdc = GetMetaFile(@"C:\Users\mrtel_000\Desktop\test.wmf");
    var res = PlayMetaFile(bmpHdc, mfHdc);
    if (!res)
    {
        throw new Win32Exception();
    }
    gfx.ReleaseHdc();
}

bmpNew.Save("demo.png");
```

The above is obviously leaking resources, but demonstrates a proper playback.

Result:

[image]
<sub>([Click for Full Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvM2N.png))</sub>

Comment: Thank you, it is now obvious that SetWinMetaFileBits screwed this image up. It seems I have to use deprecated WinAPI functions (not documented anymore on MSDN web), hope it won't be dangerous for future.

Comment: @user Mitch did a fine job here. You might accept his answer.